# Navigation Drawer does not cover an activity

Tags: android

I am writing an organiser app and I am stuck at this problem. Navigation drawer stacks itself with the listview in activity [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk78S.png) . There is no exception and the app is working, but the listview elements and navigation drawer elements are clicked at the same time.

Here is the activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EventActivity">

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">


  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrawerLayout should be the parent of your layout. Here`s my example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="end">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    //my code

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navrapoarte"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
  
      >
    //my code
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, now everything is working as was planned